# Why is the shorthand argument name $0 returning a tuple of all parameters?

Tags: swift

I was trying to define a variable that can hold a closure and ran into some difficulties using Swift's shorthand argument names. Take the following code snippet:

```
var returnAString: (String, String) -> String
returnAString = { return $0 }
```

This gives me the compile error ***'(String, String)' is not convertible to 'String'***. When I modify the closure return a string with the first argument value, I get back both argument values in a tuple.

```
println(returnAString("1", "2")) // Prints "(1, 2)"
```

However, if I modify the closure to print the second argument the correct argument is printed as expected.

```
returnAString = { $1 }
println(returnAString("1", "2")) // Prints "2"
```

I've got the feeling that I'm doing something a little silly here, but I couldn't find any explanation of why this would be happening.

Comment: `$0.0` makes it work, although as far as I can tell, it should be working the way you're trying it (or at least looks like it should).

Comment: What a counter-intuitive behaviour. Now my face looks exactly like `$0.0`.

Comment: Note that this behaviour will change in Swift 4 as per [SE-0110](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md) – a function type with n parameters will only be able to be satisfied by a function value with n parameters (therefore I believe you won't be able to implicitly ignore parameters using shorthand closure arguments – you'll either have to use both `$0` and `$1` in the body, or explicity ignore one or both of them).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Closures § Shorthand Argument Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

> ### Shorthand Argument Names
>
> …
> the number and type of the shorthand argument names will be inferred from the expected function type.

It looks like this is the expected behavior. By providing only `$0` you are inferring (at least to the system) that you want a tuple.

This only seems to be a special case of using `$0`. For example, the following cannot be compiled.

```
var returnAString3: (String, String, String) -> String
returnAString3 = { return $1 }
```

No matter how it's modified.

```
returnAString3 = { return $1.0 } // still fails.
```

Comment: That makes sense. Doesn't seem very intuitive though!

Answer (score 2):

Type inferral is treating `$0` as a tuple instead of the first argument, because you are not using the 2nd parameter.

If you just reference the 2nd parameter instead it works correctly:

```
returnAString = { $1; return $0 }
```

A proof that what I am saying is correct comes from 0x7fffffff's comment:

```
returnAString = { $0.0 }
```

which means take the first value of the `$0` tuple and return it.

Comment: It seems like you're right. If I name the parameters in the variable definition then I can actually access them like so, $0.param1, $0.param2. However, as soon as I reference $1, $0 becomes of type String and that no longer compiles.

Answer (score 0):

To the language, "multiple parameters" is the same as a single parameter that is a tuple. Since only `$0` was used, and not `$1`, etc., the compiler first guesses that there is only one parameter. And that guess is always valid because any function type can be viewed to have exactly one parameter (which may be `Void`, a tuple, or otherwise).