# Why can't I use the shorthand argument names in this default parameter value?

Tags: swift, closures

The following code isn't compiling, though it seems to me it should:

```
public typealias ACallback = (first: [Int], second: String, third: String, fourth: CustomType) -> [Int];

public func doSomething(callback: ACallback = { $0 } {
    ...
}
```

I get an error on the function declaration's line:

> '(first: [Int], second: String, third: String, fourth: CustomType)' is not convertible to '[Int]'

When I declare the function like so, it works:

```
public fund doSomething(callback: ACallback = { first, _, _, _ in first } {
```

It also makes no difference if I replace the `ACallback` with the same definition inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callback: ACallback = { $0.0 }` should be OK, I think. As the error describes, `$0` means a tuple of entire parameter list of that closure here.

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I would define the type so its arguments aren't handled like a tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question isn't a duplicate—the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607013/why-is-the-shorthand-argument-name-0-returning-a-tuple-of-all-parameters) seems to explain this behaviour.

To answer the question in your comment—you could redefine the type as a structure or a class (whatever is suitable) and be able to refer to the arguments as properties (instead of as position numbers in the tuple).