# Why don't shorthand argument names work in this Swift closure?

Tags: swift, closures

Here's a Swift function that takes in two ints and a three-arg function, and calls the passed-in function.

```
func p(x:Int, _ y:Int, _ f: (Int, Int, Int) -> ()) {
    f(x, y, 0)
}
```

I can call this just fine using both trailing closure syntax and shorthand argument names, no problem:

```
> p(1, 2) {print($0 + $1 + $2)}

3
```

That worked as expected. But in the Foundation library, there is a string method called `enumerateSubstringsInRange` defined as follows:

```
func enumerateSubstringsInRange(
      _ range: Range<Index>, 
      options opts: NSStringEnumerationOptions, 
      _ body: (substring: String?, 
               substringRange: Range<Index>, 
               enclosingRange: Range<Index>, 
               inout Bool) -> ())
```

Okay, that's easy enough: the function takes three arguments, the last of which is four-argument function. Just like my first example! Or so I thought....

I can use this function with the trailing closure syntax, but I cannot use shorthand argument names! I have no idea why. This is what I tried:

```
let s = "a b c"
"a b c".enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.characters.indices, options: .ByWords) {(w,_,_,_) in print(w!)} 

a
b
c
```

All good; I just wanted to print out the matched words, one at a time. That worked when I specified by closure as ``{(w,*,*,_) in print(w!)}`. HOWEVER, when I try to write the closure with shorthand argument syntax, disaster:

```
> "a b c".enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.characters.indices, options: .ByWords) {print($0!)}
repl.swift:9:86: error: cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type   '(substring: String?, substringRange: Range<Index>, enclosingRange: Range<Index>, inout Bool)' (aka '(substring: Optional<String>, substringRange: Range<String.CharacterView.Index>, enclosingRange: Range<String.CharacterView.Index>, inout Bool)')
```

So what did I do wrong?! The error message seems to say that closure argument `$0` is the **whole tuple of args**. And indeed, when I tried that, that sure seems to be the case!

```
>"a b c".enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.characters.indices, options: .ByWords) {print($0.0!)}

a 
b
c
```

So I'm terribly confused. Why in the first case (my function `p`, are the arguments understood to be `$0`, `$1`, etc., but in the second case, all the arguments are rolled up into a tuple? Or are they? FWIW, I found the signature of enumerateSubstringsInRange [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS91APIDiffs/Swift/Swift.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the number of parameters.

For example,

```
func test( closure: (Int,Int,Int) -> Void ){
    // do something
}
```

To make `test` works as you expect, you must specify `$2` ( 3rd argument ). The compiler will infer to the values inside tuple, otherwise it will infer to the tuple itself.

If you don't specify `$number` that match the number of parameters. For example, only specify `$1`, will make compile error.

```
// work as expected ( infer to int )
test{
    print($2)
}
test{
    print($1+$2)
}
test{
    print($0+$1+$2)
}

// not work ( infer to tuple )
test{
    print($0)
}

// not work ( cannot infer and compile error )
test{
    print($1)
}
```

There is a question relate to this question.  [Why is the shorthand argument name $0 returning a tuple of all parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607013/why-is-the-shorthand-argument-name-0-returning-a-tuple-of-all-parameters)