# Why does use of closure shorthand-named variables has to be exhaustive in a singular return expression in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

The following piece of code are erroneous in Swift.

```
func foo(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return closure(1, 2)
}

print(foo(closure: {$0}))
```

---

```
func foo(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return closure(1, 2)
}

print(foo(closure: {return $0}))
```

The error given by XCode playground is Cannot convert value of type `'(Int, Int)' to closure result type 'Int'`.

While the following pieces of code are completely fine.

```
func foo(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return closure(1, 2)
}

print(foo(closure: {$0 + $1}))
```

---

```
func foo(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
return closure(1, 2)
}
print(foo(closure: {$1; return $0}))
```

---

```
func foo(closure: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return closure(1, 2)
}

print(foo(closure: {a, b in a}))
```

It seems that in a situation where arguments to a closure are referred to by shorthand argument names, they must be used exhaustively if the the body of the closure only consists of the return expression. Why?

Comment: Related: [Why is the shorthand argument name $0 returning a tuple of all parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607013/why-is-the-shorthand-argument-name-0-returning-a-tuple-of-all-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use `$0`, the closure arguments are assumed to be a tuple instead of multiple variables `$0`, `$1` etc. So you should be able to work around this by extracting the first value of that tuple:

```
print(foo(closure: {$0.0}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "why" is like asking "why is an American football field 100 yards long?" It's because those are the rules. An anonymous function body that takes parameters must *explicitly acknowledge* all parameters. It can do this in any of three ways:

- Represent them using `$0`, `$1`, ... notation.
- Represent them using parameter names in an `in` line.
- Explicitly discard them by using `_` in an `in` line.

So, let's take a much simpler example than yours:

```
func f(_ ff:(Int)->(Void)) {}
```

As you can see, the function `f` takes one parameter, which is a function taking one parameter.

Well then, let's try handing some anonymous functions to `f`.

This is legal because we name the parameter in an `in` line:

```
f {
    myParam in
}
```

And this is legal because we accept the parameter using `$0` notation:

```
f {
    $0
}
```

And this is legal because we explicitly throw away the parameter using `_` in the `in` line:

```
f {
    _ in
}
```

But this is not legal:

```
f {
    1 // error: contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, 
    // which cannot be implicitly ignored
}
```

Comment: Is not the question asking the reason *behind* the rules, not for the rules? I'm sure we all hope there is reason in Swift's design ;-)

Comment: @CRD Like a lot of Swift's rules, it's all about making you explicitly acknowledge you know what you're doing. Consider `override`; it adds nothing (since Objective-C doesn't use it), so "why" is it required if you override an inherited member? To make you be explicit.

Comment: I think you mistook my comment, probably wasn't clear enough. Actually I think it's got more to do with the way type inference works in Swift (see @Palle's answer), that's the "why" - not because it's the rules. Type inference doesn't have to work this way, a different approach could support what the OP expected (but maybe not other things Swift does - it's all about choices). The OP asked a reasonable question.